# How to get an object inside object from json?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm creating GET method using Retrofit and need to get an object called "bus" inside another object I can call it "BusInspectionReport", what the right coding method to get it using id as query?

What I want is to get only 'bus' object contents from json. I have created a class called BusInspectionReport, and one of its parameters is 'bus' object of class Bus. Bus class is what will represent the contents of 'bus' object in json file.

Example of json file with id=1 :

```
{
    "response_code":5,
    "response_msg":"Success",
    "bus":{
        "vehicle_id":"1",
        "vehicle_plate":"ا ا ا 4389",
        "category":"ورشة",
        "category_id":2,
        "last_seen":"2019-04-15T12:19:24.4223277",
        "location":{
            "lat":0.0,
            "lon":0.0
        },
        "status":{
            "sos":false,
            "ignition":"",
            "movement":false,
            "speed":0.0
        },
            "driver":{
                "driver_id":0,
                "driver_name":""
            },
            "inspection_report":[]
        }
}
```

BusInspectionReport.java:

```
public class BusInspectionReport {

    private int response_code;
    private String response_msg;
    private Bus bus;

    public BusInspectionReport(int response_code, String response_msg, Bus bus) {
        this.response_code = response_code;
        this.response_msg = response_msg;
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public int getResponse_code() {
        return response_code;
    }

    public void setResponse_code(int response_code) {
        this.response_code = response_code;
    }

    public String getResponse_msg() {
        return response_msg;
    }

    public void setResponse_msg(String response_msg) {
        this.response_msg = response_msg;
    }

    public Bus getBus() {
        return bus;
    }

    public void setBus(Bus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }
}
```

Bus.java:

```
public class Bus {

    private String vehicle_id;
    private String vehicle_plate;
    private String category;
    private String category_id;
    private String last_seen;
    private Status status;
    private Driver driver;

    public Bus(String vehicle_id, String vehicle_plate, String category, String category_id, String last_seen, Status status, Driver driver) {
        this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
        this.vehicle_plate = vehicle_plate;
        this.category = category;
        this.category_id = category_id;
        this.last_seen = last_seen;
        this.status = status;
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getVehicle_id() {
        return vehicle_id;
    }

    public void setVehicle_id(String vehicle_id) {
        this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
    }

    public String getVehicle_plate() {
        return vehicle_plate;
    }

    public void setVehicle_plate(String vehicle_plate) {
        this.vehicle_plate = vehicle_plate;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCategory_id() {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setCategory_id(String category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getLast_seen() {
        return last_seen;
    }

    public void setLast_seen(String last_seen) {
        this.last_seen = last_seen;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Driver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

MyApi.java:

```
public interface MyApi {

    String BASE_URL = "/*BASE URL*/";

    @GET("/*API PATH*/")
    Call<Bus> getBus(@Query("id") String vehicle_id);

}
```

I'm not sure of the GET method if it's right or not, should I get the BusInspectionReport object first to get 'bus' object? or I can get 'bus' directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Call<Bus>` to `Call<BusInspectionReport>` and then get the `Bus` from the `BusInspectionReport` object

```
public interface MyApi {
    String BASE_URL = "/*BASE URL*/";
    @GET("/*API PATH*/")
    Call<BusInspectionReport> getBus(@Query("id") String vehicle_id);

}
```